# sql (oracle) to select the first 10 records, then the next 10, and so on

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I figure I might just be missing some obvious syntax but what is the sql (oracle) to select the first 10 records, then the next 10, and so on?

I tried using rownum but can seem to get rownum > X and rownum < Y to work.

llcf

Answer (score 13):

There is only a rather convoluted way to do this, which is a real pain with Oracle. They should just implement a LIMIT/OFFSET clause...

The rownum gets assigned *after* the row has been selected by the where clause, so that a rownum must always start with 1. `where rownum > x` will always evaluate to false.

Also, rownum gets assigned *before sorting is done*, so the rownum will not be in the same order as your order by says.

You can get around both problems with a subselect:

```
 select a,b,c, rn from 
    ( select a,b,c, rownum rn from 
         ( select a,b,c from the_table where x = ? order by c)
      where rownum < Y)
  where rn > X
```

If you do not need to sort (but only then), you can simplify to

```
 select a,b,c, rn from
     ( select a,b,c, rownum rn from the_table where rownum < Y )
   where rn > X
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use ROW_NUMBER() function... for example

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (ORDER BY MYFIELD) AS MYROW FROM MYTABLE A ) 
WHERE MYROW < X

SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (ORDER BY MYFIELD) AS MYROW FROM MYTABLE A ) 
WHERE MYROW BETWEEN X AND Y

SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER (ORDER BY MYFIELD) AS MYROW FROM MYTABLE A ) 
WHERE MYROW BETWEEN Y AND Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also select all rows, and only fetch 10 at a time. This works only if you can keep the cursor between the fetches, of course.