# How can I implement paging for DataGridView in Winform scenario when using Entity Framework?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, paging

All that I can find on net is for asp.net use.
All that I want is to retrieve only the page count amount of records from database every time. Isn't this possible?

The bottleneck seems to be the disposal of the context. Dunno how to resolve this.

Thanks.
Nico

Answer (score -1):

if you just need a simple sql query you can use this example:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    //
    // The name we are trying to match.
    //
    string dogName = "Fido";
    //
    // Use preset string for connection and open it.
    //
    string connectionString = ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        //
        // Description of SQL command:
        // 1. It selects all cells from rows matching the name.
        // 2. It uses LIKE operator because Name is a Text field.
        // 3. @Name must be added as a new SqlParameter.
        //
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM Dogs1 WHERE Name LIKE @Name", connection))
        {
            //
            // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
            //
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", dogName));
            //
            // Read in the SELECT results.
            //
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int count = reader[0];
            }

            // Call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

keep in mind you'll need to find out the `connectionString` to your database. depend on what database you have you can use google to find out how to do it.

Comment: i don't think you got my question right. i wasn't asking how to get the count number of some query. i wanted to get only one page amount of data every time.

Comment: @Nico what do you mean "one page amount of data"?

Comment: For example, if I plan to display 10 records in one page, then I only want to return 10 records from database every time user clicks Next/Previous/Last/First button. Got the point?

Comment: @Nico now i did. what you need is ROW_NUMBER(). this example will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869311/sql-oracle-to-select-the-first-10-records-then-the-next-10-and-so-on

Comment: i was expecting a solution to integrate the use with DGV in winform with EF. anyway, i managed to figure it out. thanks anyway.