# Get 1000 row set from Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I want to select 1000 rows at a time using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM MEMBERID_1M WHERE ROWNUM <1000
```

How do I get the next set of 1000 rows from this table in a for loop?

Comment: Please mention the Oracle version.

Comment: Standard Edition One - Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `ROW_NUMBER()` function like this: (my `id` is your PK)

```
SELECT M.* 
FROM (
    SELECT MEMBERID_1M.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) As rn
    FROM MEMBERID_1M ) M
WHERE 
    (rn <= 1000)
```

And for next:

```
SELECT M.* 
FROM (
    SELECT MEMBERID_1M.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) As rn
    FROM MEMBERID_1M ) M
WHERE 
    (rn > 1000) AND (rn <= 2000)
```

For page `:i`:

```
SELECT M.* 
FROM (
    SELECT MEMBERID_1M.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) As rn
    FROM MEMBERID_1M ) M
WHERE 
    (rn > :i * 1000) AND (rn <= (:i + 1) * 1000)
```

Comment: It gives:ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 13

Comment: I forgot to use table name before * in inner select ;).

Answer (score 0):

Reproducing the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869311/sql-oracle-to-select-the-first-10-records-then-the-next-10-and-so-on)

There is only a rather convoluted way to do this, which is a real pain with Oracle. They should just implement a LIMIT/OFFSET clause...

The rownum gets assigned *after* the row has been selected by the where clause, so that a rownum must always start with 1. `where rownum > x` will always evaluate to false.

Also, rownum gets assigned *before sorting is done*, so the rownum will not be in the same order as your order by says.

You can get around both problems with a subselect:

```
 select a,b,c, rn from 
    ( select a,b,c, rownum rn from 
         ( select a,b,c from the_table where x = ? order by c)
      where rownum < Y)
  where rn > X
```

If you do not need to sort (but only then), you can simplify to

```
 select a,b,c, rn from
     ( select a,b,c, rownum rn from the_table where rownum < Y )
   where rn > X
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be paging on server side .use this query
and more detail refer this link
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17asktom-093877.html

```
select * 
  from 
( select rownum rnum, a.*
    from (SELECT * FROM MEMBERID_1M ) a
   where rownum <= :M )
where rnum >= :N;
```